# How to reload CursorLoader after IntentService is executed

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-intent, android-cursorloader

My main activity has a fragment

MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
  fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout_for_fragment, mainFragment).commit();

In onCreate method, calls an IntentService to fetch data from an API, then saves to SQLite in app side.

Intent intent = new Intent(this, AService.class);
  startService(intent);

The main fragment init a cursor loader to query the saved data from SQLiteDB, and show them in a listview.

getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(A_LOADER, null, this);

The cursor loader finishes before data is saved, so the list view is always empty.

**How to make sure Service executes first?**  Or **How to reload data after Service finished?**

Comment: Take a look at this [blog post](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html) and its successors - a very useful series on Loader and LoaderManager

Comment: Thanks, very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Change to call initLoader when clicking a button.